# Binding an enum with a Collection, in a generic way

Tags: java, binding, enums

### The situation

I'm doing some refactoring on some code I'm working on.

I have a Collection of beans (retrieve from a database with Hibernate but it's not relevant here). These beans look like this (the model has been simplified for the sake of the demonstration) :

```
public class MyBean()
{
    private int id;
    private String key;
    private String label;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

They are stored in a `Map<Integer, MyBean>` where the key is the `MyBean` id.

On the other side, I have an enum, coming from an outside lib, not editable. It looks like this :

```
public enum ExternalEnum
{
    FIRST_VALUE("FirstValue"),
    SECOND_VALUE("SecondValue"),
    THIRD_VALUE("ThirdValue");

    // Constructor and getter
}
```

Currently, basically, the binding is done like this :

```
Map<Integer, MyBean> myBeans = retrieveFromDBThroughDAO();
ExternalEnum eeValue = fetchValueFromSomewhere();

switch (eeValue)
{
    case FIRST_VALUE:
        return myBeans.get(0);

    case SECOND_VALUE:
        return myBeans.get(1);

    case THIRD_VALUE:
        return myBeans.get(2);

    default: // In case of an unexpected modification of the enum
        return myBeans.get(0);

    // I know, case FIRST_VALUE is useless but it's for being clearer
}
```

### Issues here

1. The binding is hard coded, every modification implies a new build
2. It's kind of ugly, redundant
3. I know it could be done in a better way

### My thinking

I was thinking about outsourcing the binding in a properties file like

```
my.enum.binding.first_value=0
my.enum.binding.second_value=1
my.enum.binding.third_value=2
my.enum.binding.default=0
```

And read it in a generic way.

### My question

What do you think of my solution ? Do you think it could be improve in an other way ?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Shouldn't this be on Code Review? Oh sorry still kinda tired...

Comment: As MyBean comes from the db, I don't know to add a direct dependency to the enum

Answer (score 0):

Well you could create a custom class that is returned by the retrieveFromDBThroughDAO() that will handle the Enum, how it is mapped can still be done through the external config.

But that would centralize all changes of how to map the enums to the ids to that one class.